# When sending email also receiving the email in my inbox

Tags: c#, gmail-api

Why when sending an email from Gmail API
one email is sent to the provided email address, **but** I also receive the email in **my inbox**?

```
public ActionResult NewEmail(String from, String text, string To, string sub)
{
    GmailService service = GmailServSendMail();
    string plainText = "To:" + To + "," + from + "\r\n" + "Subject:" + sub + "\r\n" + "Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii\r\n\r\n" + text;
    var newMsg = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message();
    newMsg.Raw = Base64UrlEncode(plainText.ToString());
    List<string> labe = new List<string>();
    labe.Add("SENT");
    newMsg.LabelIds = labe;
    service.Users.Messages.Send(newMsg, "me").Execute();
    return View("Email");
}
```

Comment: look at this. it may help: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/92913/how-can-i-stop-sent-items-from-appearing-in-my-inbox

Comment: You are sending the email to *yourself*: `.Send(newMsg, "me")`. The plain text message also contains whoever the recipient is *and* the sender in the first line. It's surprising that anything is sent to the recipient at all.

Comment: @NeerajKumar when you put the sender in the *To* list, it's not a problem with GMail. The links you posted actually show that it was the *user's* fault in the first place